# Jackson to convert object to json string

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert Java POJO to JSON string. The problem I am facing is that as the number of requests increase, the time to process the conversion starts increasing. For e.g, at 100 tps, the time taken for process is 10 ms, but at 2000 tps, the time taken is 90ms. How can I avoid it? Is there a way to make it independent of tps.

Comment: if its possible cache your result json

Comment: I cannot cache it. It will be a new one everytime

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code you use, it is hard to optimize it otherwise.

There are other serialization options and JSON frameworks available. If you want to keep JSON, look for other frameworks like "json-smart": http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/
They claim to be 2-3 times faster than Jackson.

Comment: Code I am using is as below    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = null;
  AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
  AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
  AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospectorPair(primary,secondary);
  mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
   try {
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
   
      } catch (Exception e) {
    return "Unable to convert to Json object:" + obj.toString() + " Message: " + e.getMessage();
    
   }

Comment: You should be able to recycle the object mapper, that might improve performance.

Comment: How to recylce the Object Mapper?

Comment: See this link for the general hints: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance - basically you create a setup method for the object mapper and a separate method for serializing.